# How to use SetWindowsHookEx in Rust?

Tags: windows, winapi, callback, rust, hook

I am trying to figure out how to set global Windows hooks inside of Rust. I can find multiple examples for other languages, but there doesn't seem to be anything for Rust.

What I managed to get so far:

```
extern crate user32;
extern crate winapi;

const WH_KEYBOARD_LL: i32 = 13;
fn main() {
    let hook_id = user32::SetWindowsHookExA(
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
        Some(hook_callback),
        // No idea what goes here ,
        0,
    );
}

fn hook_callback(code: i32, wParam: u64, lParam: i64) -> i64 {
    // ...
}
```

The compiler complains that it needs a "system" `fn` for the callback function, but is getting a Rust `fn`, which makes sense, but I still don't know how to make that work.

From what I gathered from the documentation, the third parameter `hMod`  should point to the same module that has the callback function, and the examples in other languages uses some function that gets the current module handle, but I don't know how to do that in Rust.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The compiler complains that it needs a "system" `fn` for the callback function, but is getting a Rust `fn`, which makes sense, but I still don't know how to make that work.

The compiler actually gives you *exactly* what you need ... if you continue reading the error you'll see:

```
expected type `unsafe extern "system" fn(i32, u64, i64) -> i64`
   found type `fn(i32, u64, i64) -> i64 {hook_callback}`
```

Adding that, gives:

```
extern "system" fn hook_callback(code: i32, wParam: u64, lParam: i64) -> i64 {
    0
}
```

> From what I gathered from the documentation, the third parameter `hMod` should point to the same module that has the callback function, and the examples in other languages uses some function that gets the current module handle, but I don't know how to do that in Rust.

Again, reading further into the WinAPI documentation shows that `NULL` should be the value of this parameter if the thread ID (the last argument) specifies that its within the same process. Since you've passed zero - which the documentation states is associated with all threads in the current process ... that's what it should be... `NULL`. So now we get:

```
let hook_id =
    user32::SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Some(hook_callback), std::ptr::null_mut(), 0);
```

This compiles.

Accounting for the other errors around `unsafe` that you'll get ... this gives you (full working code):

```
extern crate user32;
extern crate winapi;

const WH_KEYBOARD_LL: i32 = 13;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let hook_id =
            user32::SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Some(hook_callback), std::ptr::null_mut(), 0);

        // Don't forget to release the hook eventually
        user32::UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook_id);
    }
}

extern "system" fn hook_callback(code: i32, wParam: u64, lParam: i64) -> i64 {
    0
}
```