# Rust Foreground Change `SetWindowsHookExW()`

Tags: windows, rust, setwindowshookex, getforegroundwindow

I'm trying to dive into kinda lower level programming with `Rust` after some experience with `Node.js`. Currently it is small application that counts time spent within specific windows opened.

I've found that I can use `windows` crate to interact with Windows API, and there is a function `GetForegroundWindow()` which works flawlessly. I can just call it with intervals to ensure user stays within same application, which would work but in my opinion not optimal way.

So, I found that with `SetWindowsHookExW()` I can have event fired when foreground window is changed. But I am currently struggling with I need to pass into it. There is `idhook` which should be `WH_CBT` id of which is `5` as I research, also there are `lpfn` and `hmod` which I completely can't understand, and `dwthreadid` which should be `0` to capture events for all windows.

I tried to research other forums/docs but found nothing useful, besides some `C#` or `C++` implementations which are pretty unfamiliar and I can't really port them into my Rust app.
Any help will be appreciated!

Update:
Thanks by this ([How to use SetWindowsHookEx in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033906/how-to-use-setwindowshookex-in-rust))

I seem to figure out that `lfpn` param is for callback function which I setup successfully, but `hmod` as I understand in my case should be NULL, I'm passing that with `std::ptr::null_mut()`, which is causing next error:

```
the trait bound `*mut _: CanInto<HMODULE>` is not satisfied 
the following other types implement trait `CanInto<T>`:
  <DtdEntity as CanInto<IInspectable>>
  <DtdEntity as CanInto<IUnknown>>
  <DtdNotation as CanInto<IInspectable>>
  <DtdNotation as CanInto<IUnknown>>
  <HCURSOR as CanInto<HICON>>
  <IInspectable as CanInto<IUnknown>>
  <IXmlCharacterData as CanInto<IInspectable>>
  <IXmlCharacterData as CanInto<IUnknown>>
and 36 others
required for `*mut _` to implement `IntoParam<HMODULE, CopyType>
```

Comment: Hard to get going, it requires DLL injection into every running process.  Get ahead with [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to monitor for EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you! That's pretty useful comment!
I can use it like that: 
`SetWindowsHookW(0x0003, Some(win_event_hook_callback))`
It compiles! But sadly, it doesn't work for some reason. This function returns `HHOOK(0)` and that's it. When window is changed nothing happens here =(. I set up endless loop with `thread::sleep` so program won't finish after setting up this hook. Any thoughts?

Comment: SetWindowsHookW???  Click the Ask Question button to properly document your new problem.